# learning python hello world script not executing

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python and learning to program in it.
I wrote a basic script

#### my.py

```
#! /bin/python
print "hello world!"
```

but this does not execute.
I did

> chmod +x my.py

and

> ./my.py

I have tried removing the blank space in my program

```
#!/bin/python
```

but even this gives me error

> bash: ./my.py: /bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Python is present on system.
I have checked the program by typing on terminal

So what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means there is no file at the path `/bin/python`

Try `which python` to see the location of the interpreter

But why not `python my.py`?

Comment: Actually I was new to python hence that idea did not came to  mind which you mentioned

Comment: On some systems you must type `python my.py` instead of `./my.py`. I'm posting this comment just for posterity for future readers.